# Pandoc - How can I get equal pdf, when building from docx to tex to pdf (docx>tex>pdf) and docx to pdf (doc>pdf)?

Tags: pdf, pandoc

I have a file called `TEST.docx` created and exported with Google Docs.

1. From `TEST.docx`, I use `pandoc` with many **variables** used by the **template** (`-V lang=fr-FR`), an include an header in preamble with my styling (`-H myconf.latex`) to produce a `.tex`.
2. From `TEST.docx`, I use `pandoc` with many **variables** used by the **template** (`-V lang=fr-FR`), an include header in preamble with my styling (`-H myconf.latex`) and `--pdf-engine=pdflatex` to produce a `.pdf`.

How, using the `.tex` source generated in **`(1)`**, can I ensure to generate a new `.pdf` identical to the pdf generated in **`(2)`**?

Comment: It is unclear, what you are asking. Which problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: Starting with a `.docx`, I am not able from a `.tex` to generate the same `.pdf`. I'd like to generate `.tex` first so I can edit a little bit the `pdf`. Eg: I wan't to reduce the  font-size by 2pt at the middle of my document.